# Using query has_many through rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 model,

Article

```
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :author
```

Author

```
has_many :articles
has_many :categories, through: :articles
```

Category

```
has_many :articles
has_many :authors, through: :articles
```

This is what I want to do,

> author/show.html.erb

```
<h5>Recent Articles</h5>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Judul Artikel</th>
   <th>Kategori</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <% Article.all.each do |author| %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= author.judul_artikel %></td>
    <td><%= author.category.nama_kategori %></td>
   </tr>
  <% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to do is when author/id present in table, it only shows category and article where id is present.

I don't know how to use query or something here

Comment: `Article.all.each do |author|` is totally wrong interpretation, you could use `Article.all.each do |article|` but it will be good by convention not by methodology.

Comment: You must provide your controller action code which render this view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you want are the articles related to that author:

Using [Hash conditions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) you can scope better the Articles model into the articles related to the author:

```
<% Article.where(author_id: @author.id).each do |author| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= author.judul_artikel %></td>
   <td><%= author.category.nama_kategori %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

But there's a better solution. Since you're using the `show` action, you should pass an instance variable (`@author`, for example). you can then use its association method as an object `@author.articles`:

```
<% @author.articles.each do |author| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= author.judul_artikel %></td>
   <td><%= author.category.nama_kategori %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```